# LineString and multiLine openlayer3

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to show lines on the map using ol.genom.lineString, my plan is in the future to implement 3 lines at the same time using multiLineString. My problem is that i cant figure out how the LineString should be implemented. this is where im at now:

http://jsfiddle.net/6RS2z/125/

```
(function(){

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()})],
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1
  })
});

 var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  //create empty vector
});

var plyFeature = new ol.Feature({
    genometry : new ol.geom.LineString([0,0,18,60], 'EPSG:4326',   'EPSG:3857')
});

vectorSource.addFeature(plyFeature);

var plyLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source : vectorSource  
})

map.addLayer(plyLayer);
```

})();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create an `ol.geom.LineString`, you provide an array of points as first constructor argument:

```
var geom = new ol.geom.LineString([[0, 0], [18, 60]]);
```

To transform the geometry to the view projection, you do the following:

```
geom.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

When you create an `ol.geom.MultiLineString`, you provide an array of linestrings as first constructor argument:

```
var multigeom = new ol.geom.MultiLineString([
  [[0, 0], [18, 60]],
  [[18, 60], [9, 30]]
]);
```

Coordinate transforms work the same for all geometry types.

Comment: thanks! this is my solution http://jsfiddle.net/6RS2z/132/ . I couldnt figure out how to have different colors on the polylines when using ol.new.multiLineString. Right now i use different layers  for each polyline so that I can decide which one to show on top. Is this a good solution? I would appreciate any advice you may have

Comment: It's better to ask about styles in a new question, because it's not really related to this one.